# How to use XRM in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm

Hello I need to convert a JS Xrm web api function into C#

```
var opp = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
  Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords(
    "dei_opportunityline",
    "?$select=_dei_vendor_value,dei_multiplier,dei_iscommission,dei_opportunitylineid&$filter=_dei_opportunity_value eq " +
      opp
  ).then(
    function success(result) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
        var newMulti = null;
        if (result.entities[i].dei_iscommission) {
          if (
            result.entities[i]["_dei_vendor_value"] ==
            "5fc8d03b-c41c-eb11-a813-000d3a31ed8d"
          ) {
            if (jcimulti != null) newMulti = jcimulti;
          } else {
            if (commulti != null) newMulti = commulti;
          }
```

For methods like .retrieveMultipleRecords, result.entities[i].dei_iscomission

is there a way to write this in C# plugin ?!

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Xrm` in C#, this is useful inside Dynamics client scripting (JS) context only. ie web form context.

For Server side (C#), you have to use `HttpClient`. [Sample code](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/287107/connect-c-console-with-web-api-dynamics-365-crm-online)

```
        HttpClient httpClient = null;
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //Default Request Headers needed to be added in the HttpClient Object
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Set the Authorization header with the Access Token received specifying the Credentials
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yourorg.api.crmx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/");
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync("dei_opportunityline?$select=_dei_vendor_value,dei_multiplier,dei_iscommission,dei_opportunitylineid&$filter=_dei_opportunity_value eq <guid>").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var records = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            //you can get dei_iscomission from above records  
        }
```

This is how we use in console application, but in plugin or workflow code - you can use Org Service to get data using Query Expression or fetchxml. Methods like `service.RetrieveMultiple` will suffice your need. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/org-service/entity-operations-query-data)

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the crmsdk nuget package in C#. Then you can connect like you want.
See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/org-service/quick-start-org-service-console-app)

This packages gives you access to the official c# SDK for XRM. the methods are much easier to use then directly calling the ODATA Web API. For an example to fetch multiple records, see https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/246665/how-to-retrieve-multiple-records-from-an-entity-in-crm-using-c
For a quick start, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/get-started-dynamics-365-web-api-csharp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the `crmsdk` NuGet package? Why does it solve this problem? As it stands, this answer relies primarily on the link to the documentation, without any specific details from this post. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize _how_ to use `crmsdk` to address this specific problem?

Comment: @JeremyCaney You want to use the Xrm SDK (or DataVerse SDK). That is fine. There is a client SDK for Javascript, that can be used for clientside extensions of dataverse/xrm (web resources, scritps, ...).  There is also a full C# SDK that works from C#. From within this SDK you can connect to XRM, and call whatever method you'd like.  The SDK works with the "OrganizationService", the official endpoint to connect to XRM from C#. It is much easier to use. 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/246665/how-to-retrieve-multiple-records-from-an-entity-in-crm-using-c

Comment: @Illeris: Oh, that's helpful background! As I suspect future readers would also find this useful, could you [edit] you answer to include that explanation?